# umask vs -m, --mode command options

Tags: command-line, permissions, umask

Is there any technical merit/necessity to numerous *nix commands (`mkdir`, `mkfifo`, `mknod`) having a `-m` (`--mode`) option?

I ask this because near as I can tell, `umask` (both the shell command and the syscall) provides everything you need to control a file's permissions:

For example, I can do this:

```
mkdir -m 700 "$my_dir"
```

..but I can just as easily do:

```
old_umask=`umask` \
&& umask 0077 \
&& mkdir "$my_dir"
umask "$old_umask"
```

To be clear, I can see that the former is much more user-friendly and convenient (especially for command-line useage), but I don't really see a *technical* advantage of the former over the latter.

Note also that I understand the merits of this flexibility at the underlying syscall level: if I want to call `open` or `sem_open` or what have you with at most 600 permissions, it makes sense that I would just pass `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` to the open syscall, never bother with the `umask` syscall, saving a syscall round-trip (or two, if I want to then reset the umask since the `umask` call modifies the current umask) and my code is simpler/cleaner. This does not apply in the command line example because the `-m`/`--mode` option of such a command will *have* to call `umask` to zero out the umask of that command's process anyway, to ensure the mode/permission bits that it's supposed to set on the new file/whatever are set. (E.g. if my shell's umask is `022`, then `mkdir -m 777 /tmp/foo` can only work as expected if it's first calling `umask` internally to zero out the umask it inherited from the shell.)

So what I want to make sure I didn't miss in my considering of the problem is, is there something you could not accomplish with just the `umask` command, without relying on the `-m`/`--mode` options of the mk* commands?

Comment: Note -m is not always equivalent to umask; mkdir -p, for example, only uses -m for the *final* directory and not intermediates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things you can't do with `umask` alone:

- create a regular file with permissions above `0666`.
- create a directory with permissons above `0777`.

So you do need `chmod` or `--mode` as well. If, for security reasons, you *never* want to create an object with temporarily higher rights than intended, `chmod` without `umask` isn't enough either. In some corner cases  you have to use even both resulting in the rather ugly sequence `umask` / `mkdir` / `chmod` / `umask`. (Example: create a group temp directory (`01770`).)

So `--mode` can be replaced with `chmod` and `umask`, but not with only one of them.

Comment: Nitpick: I understand the value of a chmod command, since that lets you change the mode of existing things.

Comment: @mtraceur You're right. I was thinking to complicated at that point.

Comment: I don't think this is inherently a justification of dedicated `-m` options, however: I can see the argument for needing a way to _limit_ permissions in the same atomic operation as file/directory/fifo/etc creation, but not so much for increasing them in the same atomic operation.

Comment: The alternative to the `-m` option is the sequence `ulimit` / `mkdir` / `chmod` / `ulimit`. If you want a minimalistic system, you can through away the `-m` option, but not `chmod`.

Comment: I presume you meant `umask` as opposed to `ulimit`, but anyway, I've accepted your answer because, along with the comments, it basically answers my question (or at least, it confirms my original thinking that it is in fact not strictly speaking necessary to have a `-m` option, but that you /do/ need chmod as well, which I forgot to mention in my original question). I would recommend adding your last comment (or a paraphrasing, doesn't really matter) into the body of your answer, as I think it's rather valuable.